как хранить товары пользователя в корзине?
Всем привет! Я пишу сайт по заказу пиццы. Сейчас делаю корзину. Обычно в интернет ресурсах выбранные элементы добавляют в массив, а массив хранят, например, в react context, но как я понимаю эти товары должны сохраняться на сервере, так как для разных пользователей могут храниться разные товары. В качестве сервера я использую json-server. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сохранять избранные товары или товары добавленные в корзину для конкретного пользователя? Правильно ли я понимаю, что они должны храниться на сервере или достаточно фронтенда?

Возможны оба варианта

а как это возможно сделать на фронтенде? localStorage? Но в localStorage память же ограничена, если например, с одного устройства будут хранить товары столько пользователей, что памяти не хватит на все, что тогда делать?
Например, в вк есть понравившиеся, избранное и там можно лайкать очень много чего, и все это будет храниться в localStorage?

Ваши формулировки какие-то непонятные. Почему вы решили, что с одного устройства будет больше чем один пользователь?

потому что это возможно. с одного устройства могут войти любое количество пользователей. У меня в вк начиная с 2015 года куча всего добавлено в избранное. И это все храниться в localStorage? А если войдет другой человек с моего устройства в вк, у которого еще больше выбранных элементов в избранных?

Я ещё кое-как могу представить, чтобы одним устройством пользовались ну два, ну может три человека. Но вы где-нибудь видели, чтобы одним устройством, одним браузером и одним профилем внутри этого браузера пользовались хотя бы человек десять? Вы уверены, что проработка этой ситуации действительно жизненно важна и без этого никак нельзя?

Можно представить ситуацию в университете, где разные студенты могут пользоваться одним и тем же компьютером. И представьте сайт, которым они все пользуются и могут что-то добавлять в избранное.  Сейчас за компьютером user_1 и у него в избранных n элементов, через час за компьютер садится user_2 и у него m элементов в избранных и тд. И все это должно постоянно храниться в localStorage? Обычно после выхода из профиля localStorage очищают, где тогда хранить элементы, чтобы при повторном входе этого пользователя правильно отображались его избранные элементы?

Нормальный университет выдаст студентам отдельные учётные записи, в каждой из которых будет свой отдельный localStorage, поэтому с точки зрения localStorage пользователь в любом случае всегда ровно один. Ну а если университет выдаёт одну общую учётную запись на всех студентов — надо валить из такого университета, там всё равно ничему хорошему не научат

Наверное, я плохо понимаю localStorage. Я полагал, что в одном браузере один localStorage и это общее хранилище и там могут храниться как разные пользователи так и их избранные элементы

Ну а уточняя мой первый комментарий — не только возможны оба варианта, но и возможны оба варианта одновременно. Добавляем требование: возможность просматривать закладки/корзину с нескольких устройств одновременно — и всё, использовать localStorage нельзя, придётся гонять данные через сервер, чтобы везде были актуальные данные. Добавляем ещё требование: возможность просматривать закладки/корзину без интернета — ой, теперь сервер недоступен, без интернета остаётся только localStorage читать. Придётся включать свой талант программирования на всю катушку и как-то выкручиваться с вот этим вот всем

Подскажите, а на сервере для объектов users просто добавить ключ "cart": [], где в массиве будут id товаров?

Ну это вы уже сами решаете, как вам удобнее делать сервер в соответствии с вашими желаниями и требованиями. Но как минимум сходу можно отметить, что в корзинах обычно ещё бывает количество товаров, которое тоже нужно будет куда-то добавить

Понял спасибо !

Может попробовать сохранить данные через LocalStorage?
